# Why is slideToggle not working here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been trying to troubleshoot this all night and I'm at my wits end. Does anybody know why this doesn't work (ie. the navigation does not pop open)

The HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="item1.html">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="item2.html">item2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="menu">
    <div id="menu-button"><span id="menu-text">Menu</span> <img src="image/nav.png"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS (It looks a little weird, I'm working on a responsive design)

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #1F5865;
}

#menu-button {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    left: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#menu-button img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
}

#nav {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Raleway, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #297585;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 0px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1F5865;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The JavaScript (located within the `<head>` tags)

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#nav").slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

Comment: That should be `$("#menu")` and `$("#nav")`. Get some sleep :)

Comment: oops. I was playing around and forgot to change that. I added them back but it still does not work

Comment: What exactly is meant by "within the tags"? You've got some fragments of code you're showing us. What does it actually look like put together?

Comment: Then there's your problem. The `menu` doesn't exist when the code runs.

Comment: You need to apply code formatting using the backtick character get inline tags to show up, like `<head>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) use # to reference an ID
2) you need to wait until the objects are available

[Live Demo using HEAD and not onload](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7uxfvosw/)

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() { // when document is ready    
  $("#menu").on("click",function(){
    $("#nav").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc - Missed that one

Comment: That was an error on my part. I originally had them in there but I was playing around with the code before I posted it. I put them back in, however it still does not work

Comment: Did you see the wrapping of $(function() {}) ?

Comment: That's it! strange, because I remember wrapping it with $(document).ready(function(){ at one (or several) points. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Id selector should begin with `#`. read more about jQuery [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
$(document).on('click','#menu',function(){
    $("#nav").slideToggle();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mh1goL2p/)

Comment: oops. I was playing around and forgot to change that. I added them back but it still does not work